# Blur Multiline TextInput

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with blur on multiline textinput.

For Android, no problem, hard return key close the keyboard and blur.

But, for iOS, return key just add a line.

How is it possible to blur a TextInput with `multiline=true` or close iOS keyboard ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its been added in React Native 0.17 release.

Check out the release notes under "iOS" for 0.17.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases